# ! on circle shape CSS3

Tags: css

using sass.

```
.tooltip{
  background: #5dc5c5;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline;
  opacity: 1!important;
  padding: 10px;
  &:before{
    color: #fff;
    content:'\0021';
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

    .tooltip:hover:after {
    background: #111;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: .5em;
    bottom: 1.35em;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    display: block;
    left: 1em;
    padding: .3em 1em;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 98;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="Tips: see instruction blah"></a>
```

Have been trying to make info '!' on the circle shape but so far it shows nothing on circle shape. Attempted both before and after but nothings show on circle :(

Insight or help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the CSS properties/rules but the problem is with the pseudo selector code in your SASS. You need to make the `:before` as `&:before` for it compile as `.tooltip:before`. Else it would compile as `.tooltip :before`.

Comment: @Harry - ah you are right I am missing '&' - thanks. One more for help - wonder if there is a way to make '!' stay rather than disappear upon hover?

Comment: It doesn't disappear on hover mate. Maybe there is something extra in your code elsewhere which is causing the issue. [Here](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/gylme) is a sample based on the code in question.

Comment: @Harry - many thanks and I will figure it out. thanks :)